# What does the error "htmlfile: invalid argument" mean? I'm getting this in excanvas.js

Tags: javascript

I'm hitting this error and I'm not really sure why.  I have a minified version of excanvas.js and something is breaking in IE, specifically on:

`var b=a.createStyleSheet();`

I'm not sure why.  Does anyone have any insight?  I can provide more information, I'm just not sure what information will help.

Comment: Are you invoking that method, or are you getting the error in that line? Maybe you can show more code, and in which line you are getting the error?

Comment: I'm getting an error on that line.  I think this is entirely contained within excanvas.js, that's why I didn't include more code.

Comment: Then you should provide some part of your html and any javascript code that you wrote...

Comment: This breaks if I have a page that just has a script tag with excanvas.  I'm hoping someone can explain what that invalid argument message might be.

Comment: Does your HTML validate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slightly old thread, but I thought it would be useful to post. There seems to be a limitation on how much style information a page can contain, which causes this error in IE6. I am able to produce an invalid argument error using this simple test page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
for(var i=0;i<32;i++) {
document.createStyleSheet();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I think this is the source of the problem.
HTH,
Russell

Comment: This is not the required solution for this question

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of excanvas.js did not fix this issue for me in IE8 so I updated line 111 of excanvas.js to the code below and I no longer get the exception. The code for this solution is from http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2010/02/bug85/.

```
  var ss = null;
  var cssText = 'canvas{display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;' +
      // default size is 300x150 in Gecko and Opera
      'text-align:left;width:300px;height:150px}';
  try{
    ss = doc.createStyleSheet();
    ss.owningElement.id = 'ex_canvas_';
    ss.cssText = cssText;
  } catch(e) {
    ss = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1];
    ss.cssText += "\r\n" + cssText;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd do is use the un-minified version.  Looks like this coming from an init function called from onreadystatechange, trying to style canvas elements, although that isn't as enlightening as one might hope.

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of excanvas fixes this for me. You can always get the newest version from [svn trunk](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/source/browse/#svn/trunk).